# JQuery - Show/Hide multiple divs

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have this working "mostly". I need to add some extra functionality to it though. On this page there is text that will be visible when the user opens the page. Then presented with multiple "buttons" that will have text associated with them.

I would like to have the "services" text become visible when you say press esc button or when you click outside the buttons.

Here is the code.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".toggles a").click(function(e) {
        var id = this.hash;
            $("#topics div:visible").not(id).fadeOut(function(){
            $(id).fadeIn();
            });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
$("#topics div:not(#services-copy)").hide();
});
```

Here is the Markup.

```
<div id="main-content">
<div class="toggles">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#archdesign"> <img src="images/whatwedo/archdesign.jpg" />
    <span>Architectural Design</span>
    </a> </li>
  <li><a href="#landscpdesign"> <img src="images/whatwedo/landscpdesign.jpg" />
    <p>Landscape Architecture</p>
    </a> </li>
  <li><a href="#lpdesign"> <img src="images/whatwedo/lpdesign.jpg" />
    <p>Land Planning</p>
    </a> </li>
  <li><a href="#intdesign"> <img src="images/whatwedo/intdesign.jpg" />
    <p>Interior Design</p>
    </a> </li>
  <li><a href="#gisdesign"> <img src="images/whatwedo/gisdesign.jpg" />
    <p>GIS</p>
    </a> </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="topics">
<div id="services-copy">
<h2>Services</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum aliquet eleifend enim nec laoreet. Donec augue felis, volutpat vel eleifend vitae, feugiat eu ipsum. </p>
</div>
<div id="archdesign">
  <h2>Architectural Design</h2>
  <br />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum aliquet eleifend enim nec laoreet. Donec augue felis, volutpat vel eleifend vitae, feugiat eu ipsum.</p>
</div>
<div id="landscpdesign">
  <h2>Landscape Architecture</h2>
  <br />
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum aliquet eleifend enim nec laoreet. Donec augue felis, volutpat vel eleifend vitae, feugiat eu ipsum.</p>
</div>
<div id="lpdesign">
  <h2>Land Planning</h2>
  <br />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum aliquet eleifend enim nec laoreet. Donec augue felis, volutpat vel eleifend vitae, feugiat eu ipsum.</p>
</div>
<div id="intdesign">
  <h2>Interior Design</h2>
  <br />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum aliquet eleifend enim nec laoreet. Donec augue felis, volutpat vel eleifend vitae, feugiat eu ipsum.</p>
</div>
<div id="gisdesign">
  <h2>GIS</h2>
  <br />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum aliquet eleifend enim nec laoreet. Donec augue felis, volutpat vel eleifend vitae, feugiat eu ipsum.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div><!-- End of Main-Content -->
```

This page can be viewed here [Problem Page](http://www.vagarchitects.com/what-we-do/)

Any tips or suggestions would be sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
function fader(id) {
    $("#topics div:visible").not(id).fadeOut(function() {
        $(id).fadeIn();
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".toggles a").click(function(e) {
        fader(this.hash);
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $("body").click(function(e) {
        fader("#services-copy");
    });
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) {
            fader("#services-copy");
        }
    });

    $("#topics div:not(#services-copy)").hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gfzpZ/4/

Comment: That is it! Thank you very much, I have been working on this for a while. Much Much appreciated!